# Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger not hitting breakpoints

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have recently deployed my ASP.NET Core application to my IIS8 server. However due to some issues, I have to remotely debug it.

I installed the Remote Debugger and managed to connect to the server and Attach a process.

However, I am unsure of what to attach from there. I have tried attaching all dotnet.exe and w3wp.exe processes but each time I do that, my breakpoint turns white and says that it won't hit.

I took a look at my Modules tab and for some reason, my symbols aren't loaded for my application dlls. I have made sure that the configuration is Debug and that the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is Development.

Currently this is what I am doing:

1. Run the Remote debugger on the IIS server
2. Run the website on my local laptop
3. Attach a process in Visual Studio

Comment: Do you actually have the symbols on that remote server?

Comment: Yes, in the folder where the dlls are located, I can see the pdb files

Comment: you could try this troubleshooting steps:  check the symbol file status (go to Debug -> Windows -> Modules window and check the symbol file status). Ensure that debugging is enabled  <compilation debug="true" />. [Remote Debug ASP.NET Core on a Remote IIS Computer in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-computer?view=vs-2019)

Comment: The process that you should attached to is one of the dotnet.exe processes, since this is dotnet core.  Also, are you certain that the code in Visual Studio is identical to the code which is running on the server?   If they don't match you won't be able to debug.

Comment: Hi @DJordan, yes I am sure that the code is identical. I'll keep trying.

Comment: did you check that debugging is enabled or not.  debugging is enabled <compilation debug="true" />